# TFS website build error

Tags: .net, tfs, build, web, tfs-2015

I have a problem using TFS to build a website, it's not a .NET project but an old website, without a csproj file, just the web.config file.

In the web.config file, is referenced the "System.Web.Extensions" dll like this in system.web key :

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Messaging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Configuration.Install, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
```

and a tag prefix is declared like this also in system.web key :

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

In the code, this tag prefix is used as this :

```
ASP.xxx_controls_customcontrol1_ascx userControl = ctrl as ASP.xxx_controls_customcontrol1_ascx;
```

The TFS build of the solution containing this web site fails with this error :

```
##[error]XXX\XXX\XXXXXX\Controls\uicCustomControl1.ascx.cs(93,0): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'xxx_controls_customcontrol1_ascx' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

*I added the System.Web.Extensions.dll file in the bin folder and I checkin this file in the TFS, but I still have this error.*

Any help ?

Thank you.

Comment: According to the error it looks like you are missing `'xxx_controls_customcontrol1_ascx'` somewhere in the code (line 93 of `uicCustomControl1.ascx.cs`), but trying to reference it. To fix make sure the reference is included in the solution. Hope that helps.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How's your build definition like? Are you able to get a successful build on build agent machine manually?

Comment: In my visual studio no problem, but with TFS, I have this problem. TFS is version 2015, I need to check but we are not in 2017.

Comment: @b.o.Where did the assemblies locate when you build in VS? Did you build your project on build agent machine with the source get from TFS? Could you share your build definition? Please try to use Nuget to restore your package during build.

Comment: Hi Cece, depedencides are in Nuget. In Visual Studio, they are restored and they appear in the bin folder. I check in only the .refresh file in source control. In TFS, the workflow first get source, restore Nuget packages and build. I will be able to connect to the build machine in 1 week because the administrator is not available. I will give you a feedback.

Comment: @b.o.You could also check your build log to see whether all packages are restored. If possible, you can share the entire log here.